# Are North American children adopting British accents because of Peppa Pig?

Tags: children, language, television

Several news items have surfaced today which report that North American children are adopting British accents at a very young age due to watching Peppa Pig episodes. The only source quoted is [Romper](https://www.romper.com/p/toddlers-who-adopt-peppa-pigs-accent-are-totally-bingly-bongly-normal-say-experts-15915675) which does not seem, to me, to be what I would term an 'academic' source.

Is there any other source for this ?

If it were true I would have expected comments to surface in the UK first, regarding a regional effect within the UK.

[ITV NEWS](https://www.itv.com/news/2019-02-12/american-children-develop-british-accent-after-watching-peppa-pig/)

Comment: It seems to me that the effect of national broadcasting on regional accents had been noted in the UK for decades, so I would hardly expect Peppa Pig to attract special notice in that regard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The Guardian did a short piece](https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2019/feb/14/peppa-pig-american-children-british-accents) on this and the bottom line is straightforward:

> American kids may have picked up a Britishism or two, but the claim that they’re developing a whole accent based off a cartoon is, according to linguistics experts, likely exaggerated.

The experts quoted in the article explain that mimicking specific words and developing an accent are two very different things.

Comment: My daughter, when talking about the show, says "baby Alexahnder" in a British accent, but besides that she has a very thick New Jersey accent, complete with the tensed vowel dipthongs in words like "pants" and "hand." She doesn't use a British accent when she isn't talking about the show.

Comment: Several of my favorite TV shows as a child were Canadian, but I never developed Canadian raising and still engage in Philadelphia short-A tensing similar to your daughter.